# XmlSerializer - Serialize elements without parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so this is going to be fun!

I've got the following structure that I want to convert to xml. I need to include all the sub elements from the inner object, without the inner object as a node.

```
class element1
{
    element1.1
    {
        element1.1.1,
        element1.1.2,
        element1.1.3,
        element1.1.4,
    }
}
```

In other words, how can I serialize that to the following?

```
<element1>
    <element1.1.1 />
    <element1.1.2 />
    <element1.1.3 />
    <element1.1.4 />
</element1>
```

I'm trying different combinations with the xmlelement, XmlIgnore, etc. but non seem to work until now.

Any word of advice would be deeply appreciated!

The code here would be :

```
[XmlElement("Element1")]
public class Element1
{
   [XmlElement("Element11")]
   public string Element11 {get;set;}

   [XmlElement("Element12")]
   public Element12 Element12 {get;set;}

}

public class Element12 
{
    [XmlElement("element121")]
    public string element1{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("element122")]
    public string element2{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("element123")]
    public string element3{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("element124")]
    public string element4{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you make the class element1 valid c# code ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. `XmlSerializer` makes the assumption that the model you want to serialize is shaped *roughly* like the xml you want. There are some minor tweaks you can do, but this is not one of them. If the problem is that your domain model has an extra layer, then the solution is simple: ***don't serialize your domain model***. Introduce a new set of DTO classes that exist **solely** for the purpose of xml serialization, and transform your data into the DTO model prior to serialization.

Comment: ok, I roughly had a twinkling it would be that way, but still hoped there was a way around it. Thanks for the information.